# Ranger Attack Bonus seems too high

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, armor-class, proficiency

I'm DM for my group of friends and have a question about our Ranger.  He was level 6 last session, and had a +11 to hit.  +5 from DEX, +3 prof, +2 from Archery style, and +1 from his bow.  Against the Frost Giant (AC 16) they fought, with his +11, he only had to roll a 5 or higher to hit it, or 80% chance.  So naturally, he hit every time he shot at it.

To me, this just seems like he has such a low margin of failure.  Am I just over thinking this or am I just missing something?

Comment: *He is also using a homebrewed class, believe it's called Shadow Walker and can make a clone of himself.* That from your comment below the answer.  You probably should have included that in your question, since that homebrew significantly strengthens this Ranger over the standard in the PHB.  The "attack bonus too high" isn't the root issue.

Comment: The damage I don't have a problem with, just how often he hits I wasn't sure about. He often forgets to use both Hunters Mark and the clone  at the same time, so the damage is consistent 90% of the time.

Comment: Keep in mind that, in this edition, hit points are a abstract measure of "will to live". Your PC can be just "wearing him out" until the giant is bloodied.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### That is Right.

+5 means he has a 20 or 21 in dex.  Getting to 20 by level 6 is hard (considering that they've only got one ASI), but possible using rolling for stats. The +2 and +3 are correct, and you allowed the +1 bow (which isn't unreasonable).

When not rolling for stats, the standard array max is 15 + 2 from race + 2 from ASI, i.e. 19 ― a +4 instead of a +5.

Remember, these are epic characters who fight, and shoot, a lot -- it is their job in life.  Hitting 80% against AC 16 makes sense by level 6.  The damage from even a longbow is only 1d8 + 5 (+1 from magic weapon above?) which isn't a spectacular DPR when you multiply it out. I mean, it isn't bad, but it isn't as high as some other classes.  Moreover, certain classes peak at different levels.  Even taking Hunter's Mark into account, it compares pretty well with the other classes' DPR.

#### Consider the other classes at the same level:

The fighter has fighting style, extra attack and action surge by then.

The barbarian has +2 rage damage, reckless attack and extra attack.

The Paladin has smites, fighting styles, and extra attack.

The Warlock can be doing 2 EB blasts each doing (spell attack 1d20 + 4) at 1d10 + 4 (+ 1d6 hex), pushing 10ft from 300ft away by then.

#### Your DPR Might be too High from Homebrew

Adding another 1d6 or 1d8 to an attack on top of Hunter's Mark will almost certainly unbalance a game, unless the whole party has extra buffs beyond stock +1 weapons.

Comment: Yeah he has a 20 in DEX because he is a Wood Elf, and I can't remember if he rolled 18 for that stat or used his ASI.

He is also using a homebrewed class, believe it's called Shadow Walker and can make a clone of himself.  So it adds an extra d6 or d8 of damage on each attack (he can Extra Attack since 5th level).

Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Just added to the above comment, but he usually forgets to use both the clone and Hunters Mark at the same time. Plus it can only attack once per turn, it has to roll to attack, and only deals half damage.

Comment: This answer has all the right details, but I feel it's missing a summary that would point out the *reason* this isn't weird: rangers can get very good at hitting accurately, but sacrifice other things (like damage) to do so.